# Updating data in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, post

I'm trying to update data in my database with this function

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
$name = $_POST["name"];
$surname = $_POST["surname"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$mysql_qry = "UPDATE user_data (name, surname, age, username, password) values ('$name','$surname','$age','$username','$password')";
if($conn->query($mysql_qry) === TRUE) {
echo "Success!";
}
else {
echo "Something is wrong :( Error: " . $mysql_qry . "<br>" . $caonn->error;
}
$conn->close();
```

but it always goes to Error. Can you help me with this? I was trying to put data from keyboard but it's  not working either.

I've changed this line

```
$mysql_qry = "UPDATE user_data SET name = '$name'";
```

and now it's working but its changing all the names in database and I want to change only one record...

Comment: shouldn't that be insert? your question title and content is confusing, title is updating but looking at the code, it seems that your intent is to insert a new row

Comment: What kind of error message are you getting?

Comment: I won't use my close hammer, but I bet [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) solves your problem whatever it is (you never told your problem).

Comment: @ghost I was using code which was already written. It was insert but I need to update this data.

Comment: your syntax is all wonkey: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: if update is your intent, then use an ID and point to it in your where clause in the update query http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: post update, now you need to add: `WHERE id=XXXX`

Comment: can I write smth like WHER id=current id?

Comment: `$caonn` huh? typo here.

Comment: Lord only knows if those POST arrays contains values and what they are.

Comment: and what would "current id" be? php\mysql is not psychic

Comment: @Fred-ii- it suppose to be $conn 

POST values contains strings which are typed by the user.

Comment: Add WHERE id=THAT_ID and you will be fine. THAT_ID or 'THAT_ID' depending on whether the "id" field in the database is a number or text, respectively (without apostrophes if it's a number, and with apostrophes if it is a text field).

Answer (score 0):

Add WHERE id=THAT_ID and you will be fine. THAT_ID or 'THAT_ID' depending on whether the "id" field in the database is a number or text, respectively (without apostrophes if it's a number, and with apostrophes if it is a text field). Off course, change THAT_ID to whatever id you want.

Comment: sure, I get it but I want

Comment: sure, I get it but I want it to check it itself. I've got the login formula before that, and it suppose to take id of a user who is currently loged

Comment: Try using $_SESSION variable then and putting user id inside that($_SESSION["user_id"] = SOME_NUMBER before you do anything else). Then you can (prior to it being filtered for illegal characters) put it as THAT_ID.

Comment: If you want to be more specific, open another question and ask how to store user id in a session, because it really depends on how you are handling the user id in the session. But you can upvote my comments and my answer and you can feel free to accept it as an answer to THIS question.